# 1998 BMW 328i Inline 6 cranks but won't start

Tags: bmw, cranks-wont-run

- Cranks but won't start
- The fuel pump cuts on and I'm getting fuel up to the filter so halfway
- I'm getting spark cause it starts off starting fluid

I've tried everything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is everything? What kind of pressure are you seeing at the fuel rail? Is the immobilizer active? OBD2 codes? EOBD2 codes?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your issue is with fuel supply. Possible things to check for:

- a clogged fuel filter
- a bad fuel pressure regulator

Both of these can cause insufficient pressure in the fuel rail, resulting in a lack of fuel delivery to the cylinders.